# Problem to use a component as children of MenuTrigger

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I have a component called `AvatarMenu` and inside of this component his built like this.

### AvatarMenu component

```
export function AvatarMenu() {
  return (
    <IconButton>
      <ProfileContainer>
        <Avatar />
        <Icon
          name="caret-down"
          width={RFValue(8)}
          height={RFValue(4)}
          style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}
        />
      </ProfileContainer>
    </IconButton>
  )
}
```

And I would like to use this component with the `MenuTrigger` wrapper, but it does not work, like something this

```
<MenuTrigger>
   {/* <Icon name="trash" width={RFValue(18)} height={RFValue(20)} /> */}
   <AvatarMenu />
</MenuTrigger>
```

But if I comment the `AvatarMenu` and uncomment the `Icon` it works.
Because I would like to do something like this
[image]

Comment: not sure what's not working... but only thing that caches my eyes is that your avatarMenu has button inside - you should let MenuTrigger handle the clicks - not to be "catched" by your button

Comment: alternatively - use your button to trigger menu programatically but it is more "hacking"